# UTF 8 byte length of a string in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, validation, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to add in cell data validation for a string length to be between 8 and 16 and the max byte length less than 40(UTF8 encoding).

I created a data validation using the excel active support:
*Data validation(data tab -> Data Validation (between Remove Duplicates and Consolidate in excel 2016 mac)), In Settings tab*, there is validation

```
criteria:
Validation Criteria:
Allow: Text Length
Data : between
Min : 8 & Max : 16
```

Though the above validation satisfies all the restrictions i have(8

For other languages(say Japanese), though the string length is being counted though physical length(Eg : `"こんにちはこんにちはこんにちは"`, hellohellohello in Japanese), the UTF8 byte value is 45 bytes, which is the violation of the 40 bytes, thought the length is only 15.

I found "LENB" function in excel, but it is giving the value as 30(instead of 45). I think it is based on different encoding(ansi maybe)

I found the UNICODE function which gives the unicode number of the first character(12371) in the above case. But i don't see how can i get the byte value from this number(3 bytes is the value for the first character(こ)).

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Unicode value, you can compute how many bytes a particular one will take. <128 is 1 byte, else <2048 is 2, else <65536 is 3, else 4.

Comment: Is there a way to get this for the entire string in a cell? Like a loop in the excel(not in VBA).

Comment: @tharunreddych, not that I know of.  I would write a VBA function.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and here is the solution without VBA based on the answer above + [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/convert-string-to-array) article. Assuming you have a string in A1:

```
=SUM(
    IF(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<128, 1,
    IF(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<2048, 2,
    IF(UNICODE(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<65536, 3, 4
))))
```

Don't forget to use array function (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) when leaving the cell :)